# Should I partition?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have installed ubuntu on my pc and I am wondering if partitioning my hard drive is possible? If that is possible, is it necessary for me to do it?

Comment: Question really doesn't make sense: if you know that partitioning exists, then by definition it is possible.  Necessary?  For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, it is possible to change partitions. You should use Gparted software for this purpose.
2. No, it is not necessary to make partitions, as system installer has already made them for you.

See the links:http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use gparted or disk utility to make partitions of your disk. Another, partition on ubuntu is the same way to backup your dato like D: E: f: drives of windows.